# How do I simulate keystrokes to a React input box so that it's treated like a user typed it? (update virtual DOM state, not just real DOM)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I have some input box that I'd like to change the value of via some Javascript, I'm trying to write a Chrome extension that makes certain repetitive tasks easier. The website that I'm trying to do this on is built with React, I do not have access to the server side of this website. The problem I'm having I think has something to do with the way React works, in that React has a virtual DOM, and me changing the DOM does not change the Virtual DOM, which is what React is looking at when I click the "ok" button, not the real DOM.

Step 1: go into the chrome console and type `document.getElementById("serialNoScanner").value = "123456"`, doing this makes the numbers appear in the box

Step 2: click the "ok" box manually (not with JS, with my mouse)

Step 3: nothing happens (because the virtual DOM hasn't updated?)

Step 4: if I delete a character in the textbox manually (not via JS), and then type the same character back in, the ok button still does nothing. (weird)

Step 5: if I type in a character manually (not via JS), then click ok, making sure that it's a different value than what I entered with Javascript, **it works**. Huh?

[image: troublesome box]

Note: this problem can be replicated on ChatGPT, which is also built on React; if you change the value of the input box via JS, the "send" button remains gray.

I just need to trick React into changing the virtual DOM state of the input box's value through Javascript, is this possible? Or maybe the [immutable isTrusted property of events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted) prevents this?

Things I've tried...

```js
var inputElement = document.getElementById('serialNoScanner');
var customEvent = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });
inputElement.value = 'New Value';
inputElement.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
```

```js
inputElement.focus()
inputElement.blur()
```

If anyone has any experience building Chrome Extensions for sites built with React, any insight on this problem would be incredibly useful. I would use Selenium, but our firewalls do not like Selenium. Thanks!

Comment: Try the deprecated document.execCommand, [example](/a/57900849).

Comment: @wOxxOm It works! I spent all day on this, thank you!!! :)